# Restart heroku dyno in nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want to restart a nodejs app to change its ip. How would I do this within the app itself? I have tried forcing a crash however if the app crashes twice within ten minutes, then heroku will restart the dyno ten minutes after the first crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/jclem/node-heroku-client) node wrapper for the v3 API and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-restart) api command.

You'll likely need to create some sort of condition that triggers this, if it *really* needs to be done from within the app itself.

Comment: The linked api wrapper is a fork, the official library is here: https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client

Answer (score 69):

If you have the Heroku CLI installed, you can run `heroku restart` in the folder of your application or run `heroku restart --app application_name`.

If you don't have it installed, you can find information about it [here](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of "How would I do this within the app itself?"

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's asking how to do it programatically

Answer (score 13):

Using the [Heroku v3 API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) it is possible using the [request node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var token = 'youAPIKeyHere';
var appName = 'yourAppName here';
var dynoName = 'yourDynoHere';

var request = require('request');

request.delete(
    {
        url: 'https://api.heroku.com/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
        // Do stuff
    }
);
```

---

There is also a [node wrapper](https://github.com/heroku/node-heroku-client) that provides a similar experience, but is poorly documented and requires an understanding of the [v3 API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) anyway

```
var token = 'youAPIKeyHere';
var appName = 'yourAppName here';
var dynoName = 'yourDynoHere';

var Heroku = require('heroku-client');

var heroku = new Heroku({ token: token });
    heroku .delete('/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/' + dynoName)
           .then( x => console.log(x) );
```

---

I also found it useful to experiment in browser with this code

```
var token = 'youAPIKeyHere';
var appName = 'yourAppName here';
var dynoName = 'yourDynoHere';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(
        'DELETE',
        'https://api.heroku.com/apps/' + appName + '/dynos/' + dynoName
    );
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send();
```

---

- I personally did find using the delete method a bit concerning. Caution should be taken with using the `delete` method and the `/apps/$$appName$$` endpoint alone will delete the app. This is from personal experience
- For any of the above, if you omit the dyno name, you will restart all dynos under the app

Answer (score 9):

You can restart the nodejs dynos right from the web dashboard of heroku :

**Dashboard -> More -> Restart all dynos**

[image]